# Read file with firebase function

Tags: typescript, firebase, file, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've got a Firebase Function and want to read a html file, stored in a subfolder.

```
── functions
    ├── src
    |   ├── index.ts // Here is the function
    |   ├── html
    |   |   ├── template.html // the file I want to read
```

I tried to read the file via  `const html = fs.readFileSync('./html/template.html');` but it always tells me

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './html/template.html'
> at Object.openSync

I worked trough almost every question on stackoverflow concerning this topic but nothing worked for me. I also tried placing the file in the same folder as the function but it always gives me the error.

Do I need to install some package or import the file in some way to access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [`path.resolve()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths) method, which will resolve your path into an absolute path, before passing it to the [`fs.readdirSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) method. So the following should do the trick:

```
    const path = require('path');

    // ...

    let content = fs.readFileSync(
        path.resolve('./html/template.html')
    );
```

Comment: thanks, this did the trick! I also had to change the path a little to "src/html/template.html" and now it works.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone coming into this post from the search results...

The solution to this isn't using `path.resolve`.

The problem here is that, `fs.readFileSync` resolves paths relative to `process.cwd()` (the directory node was executed from). In the case of firebase functions, this will always be the directory defined for `source` in `firebase.json` (by default, the `functions` directory).
This functionality is documented here:
https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths

> If, after processing all given path segments, an absolute path has not yet been generated, the current working directory is used.

`path.resolve` has the same behavior. It always resolves to an absolute path. If the path you pass in is not absolute, it prepends `process.cwd()` to it.
It doesn't look like this is documented in the Node docs, but you can see for yourself here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/029d1fd797975ef89b867f9d606257f0f070a462/lib/path.js#L1017

You can solve this in two ways:

- Using a path relative to your functions root dir (`src/html/template.html` in this case)
- Using `__dirname` (`path.resolve(__dirname, './html/template.html')`

`__dirname` is a variable that will always return an absolute path to the directory of the current file that is being executed.